# Angular/Restangular, how to pass data to url like $routeParams with angular-resource

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I asked this question earlier for angular-resources and I got it working, but now I have moved on to using restangular.

I have a view `/models` that gets data from `storage/models.json`, and I set that up to work fine with restangular.

Now I want to have a view such as `/models/:modelId` that would get data from `storage/individual/:modelId.json` with :modelId being the respective Id of the model, obviously, and I am having troubles setting this up with restangular. I got it working with angular-resources but restangular has many features that I will benefit from in the future so I decided to make the switch.

Can someone point me in the right direction? The GitHub page doesn't really talk about routeParams and I can't find examples doing what I'm trying to achieve, though I may have overlooked it.

**ModelsCtrl.js:**

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('swoleincApp')
    .controller('ModelsCtrl', ['ModelsService', '$scope', ModelsCtrl]);

function ModelsCtrl(ModelsService, $scope) {
    ModelsService
        .then(function(allModels) {
            $scope.models = allModels;
        });
}
```

**ModelsService.js:**

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('swoleincApp')
    .factory('ModelsService', ['Restangular', ModelsService]);

function ModelsService(Restangular) {
    return Restangular
        .service('app/storage/models.json')
        .getList();
}
```

The above two examples work well together and give me the desired results.

I'm trying to do something such as this for the second route but I get a 404 because ":modelId" is being used in the url as opposed to the actual model Id.

**IndividualCtrl.js:**

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('swoleincApp')
    .controller('IndividualCtrl', ['Individual', '$scope', IndividualCtrl]);

function IndividualCtrl(Individual, $scope) {
    Individual
        .then(function(individual) {
            $scope.model = individual;
        });
}
```

**IndividualService.js:**

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('swoleincApp')
    .factory('Individual', ['Restangular', IndividualService]);

function IndividualService(Restangular) {
    return Restangular
        .one('storage/individual/:modelId.json')
        .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your service change

```
Restangular
        .one('storage/individual/:modelId' + '.json')
        .get();
```

to

```
Restangular
        .one('storage/individual/', actualModelId)
        .get();
```

Then wherever you are configuring your module you need to add the suffix:

```
RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix(".json");
```

(from Restangular docs)
If all of your requests require to send some suffix to work, you can set it here. For example, if you need to send the format like /users/123.json you can add that .json to the suffix using the setRequestSuffix method

Comment: I tried this and just get errors. Either I'm implementing incorrectly or you're misunderstanding. For example, /models view loads all models. Each model has link to /models/:modelId with :modelId being the string that leads to their .json file. I want it such that when that link is clicked, the /models/:modelId view is loaded with the storage/individual/:modelId.json file being used for data. I had this set up easily with angular-resource using routeParams but can't find examples for restangular.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem

Changed this:

```
Restangular
        .one('storage/individual/:modelId' + '.json')
        .get();
```

To this:

```
Restangular
        .one('storage/individual/', $route.current.params.modelId + '.json')
        .get();
```

And added $route to the controller.